# Is there a way to manage imports of subclasses by inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, import, subclass

Is there a way to manage imports of subclasses by inheritance?

I know that this isn't the purpose of inheritance, but I would like to do so, because I have a sort of java source template for the QA-people in my company. I don't want them to worry about imports when pasting java-ified selenese inside the java template.

Do you know of any frameworks, annotations or the like, that is able to do so?

Example of what I mean (with an imaginary `@inherit` annotation):

```
@inherit
import xyz.ABC
class Super{
}
```

And now the subclass doesn't need to import ABC anymore:

```
class Sub extends Super {
     ABC abc;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify on *importing a subclass* - a superclass usually doesn't care about its subclasses - I wouldn't expect `import` statements for subclasses.

Comment: I tried to clarify what a mean by giving an example with an imagenary annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not exactly know if it is possible to annotated import statements ([they're not in the list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7) and I can't try it on the fly) and I'm sure, that it can't be done with apt, because the annotation is not defined on the class that has to be compiled.

*But* you could tag the import statements with annotations (if possible), javaDoc tags or predefined comments and use a custom tool to reads this information from the superclasses source file and modify the source code before it gets compiled.

You'd need a library that can be used to parse java source files.

---

As an alternative - you may be able to provide/generate the source files with fully qualified classnames only, so that the classes won't need any import statements at all:

```
class Sub extends Super {
     xyz.ABC abc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as you can imagine this isn't pressing enough to get into source code preprocessing, as it would only be syntactical sugar. I wondered if somebody already did just that. Unfortunately someone downvoted my question, so it won't find any answer soon...